# trying to load data frm GS Bucket to CloudSQL SQL Server table, running this script in CloudShell

Tags: csv, google-cloud-sql, google-bucket

I have the CSV file in GSBucket, and created the empty table in CloudSQL , and now I want to load data from GsBucket CSV to CloudSQL SQL Server table (existing), if I am using below command on CloudShell:

```
gcloud sql import csv testinstance gs://testbucketsabir/covid_clean.csv --database=TestDb --table=covid_clean --quiet
```

I get this error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.sql.import.csv) HTTPError 400: Unknown export file type

Please help a beginner - I want to know where the problem is and what is going wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/import-export#gcloud), `CSV` is not currently supported in `Cloud SQL` and `SQL Server` :

> Note: In Cloud SQL, the current SQL Server support for imports and
> exports consists of the following: Importing databases using BAK and
> SQL files. Exporting databases using BAK files.

Importing `CSV` is supported in `Cloud SQL` with `MySQL` or `PostgresSQL` databses.

If it's mandatory in you case to keep `SQL Server` database, you have to use BAK or SQL files : export to SQL files, then import it to `Cloud SQL`/`SQL Server`.